# Browse is slowing down for a JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, for-loop, math, browser, binary

I'm working on a JavaScript library for me. This library will help you to convert a binary number into a decimal number. The default JavaScript function can only convert before point (integers). But this code will convert floating numbers also (hopefully).

In order to test this when I ran this code on Firefox returned,

> This page is slowed down your browser.

& Google Chrome returned nothing but just loading.

So I want to know what is the problem??
Here is my code

```js
var x = "101.11";
var r = 0;
var ra = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
  if (x.charAt(i) == ".") {
    var Ap = i;
  }
}

for (var j = 0; j < (x.length - Ap); ++j) {
  var a = x.charAt(j);
  r = r + a * Math.pow(2, ((x.length - Ap - 1) - j));
}

for (var k = Ap + 1;
  (x.length - Ap) < k; ++k) {
  var b = x.charAt(k);
  ra = ra + b * Math.pow(2, (Ap - k));
}
document.write(r);
if (ra <= 0) {
  document.write("." + ra);
}
```

Comment: This condition is never met: `(x.length - Ap) < k`. Did you mean the increasing part to be `--k`?

Comment: Yep, in the first iteration of the third loop `k = 4`, `x.length - Ap = 3`, and `k` is only increasing.

Comment: ra = ra + b * Math.pow(2, (Ap - k)); I want the negative value of (Ap-k) in this equation.

Comment: That expression doesn't change any values of the for loop's condition or the incrementer. Notice, that the `k` loop is currently infinite, you've to fix that first.

Comment: Yes, I've got it. Thanks 

Comment: Why not comment out section by section of this code to spot any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. I'm very much thankful to you people.

```
/*

It's a dumb library for converting binary   fraction number into a desimal number.
Created by : Adib Rahman
Last update : 12:36 30/01/2020

*/

function print(something)
{
document.write(something);
}

var x = "010101010.111";
var r = 0;
var ra = 0;
for(var i=0;i<x.length;++i)
{
    if(x.charAt (i)== ".")
{
var Ap=i;
}
}

var beforePoint = (x.length-(x.length-Ap-1))-1;
var afterPoint = x.length-Ap-1;

for(var j=0;j<beforePoint;++j)
{
r = r+(x.charAt(j))*Math.pow(2,(beforePoint-j-1));
}

for(var k=Ap+1;k<x.length;++k)
{
var ra = ra+(x.charAt(k))*Math.pow(2,(Ap-k));
}
//Final Result
if(ra >=0)
{
print(r+ra);
}
else
{
print(r);
}
```